# Setter not called when call weakSelf in block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

When we need to call self in a block, we usually do as this:

```
__typeof(&*self) __weak weakSelf = self;
```

The question is, when you call `weakSelf.prop = @"string"` in block, the setter `setProp:` will never be called.

But if you define like this:

```
__typeof(&*self) fakeSelf = self;
```

The problem solved.

Anyone could explain why? And any potential problem?

Comment: First off, `&*` is redundant (the address of the pointer dereferencing something is just something).  Second, if it isn't being called, then your class is being deallocated before it's able to evaluate in the block.

Comment: @CodaFi The `&*` once served to remove the implicit `__strong` from the type of self. It's not needed any more, though.

Comment: "When we need to call self in a block, we usually do as this:" No, "we" don't "usually do it like this". We do this only when we see that there would be a specific problem (retain cycle) in the particular way we use it. In many coding patterns, retaining `self` by a block is necessary for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `typeof` is part of C11 and supported as an extension in older language version by clang. No need to use (implementation private) `__typeof`
2. No `&*self` hackery needed any more. clang supports the plain `typeof(self)` since a while (v3.1, Xcode 4.4).
3. `weakself.prop = ...` alway is a synonym for `[weakself setProp:...]`. This does not change when declaring the target `__weak`.

How do you come to the conclusion the accessor would not be called?

If you miss a log message or breakpoint hit maybe the target `weakSelf` was already deallocated and the variable was set to nil. This would of course prevent the accessor from being called.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer. But I wonder how did you know the second answer?